# How do I get the mouse position on a gameobject in unity?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I have currently started a developing a pixel art program in unity. I started with getting the mouse coordinates(x, y) on the ui image(texture) I used the code below but the get the mouse position in world space. I wanna get it in the space of the ui image only. The texture image is 32, 32 pixel wide and tall  (x, y respected)

```
[SerializeField] private Text coordinatesText;
private Vector3 mousePos;
private float mouseX, mouseY;

void Update()
{
    mousePos = Input.mousePosition;
    mouseX = mousePos.x;
    mouseY = mousePos.y;

    coordinatesText.text = (mouseX + ", " + mouseY).ToString();
}
```

For like, when I hover the mouse on the very bottom left of the texture, which is a ui image, I get 0, 0 and when it's in the very top right, it's 32, 32.

Thanks in advance for your help!

Comment: Which render mode on your `Canvas` are you using to render your UI?

Comment: Screen Space Camera with my main camera

Comment: Added an example.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Depending on the [`Render Mode`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Canvas-renderMode.html) your `Canvas` is set to, the answer differs ever so slightly. I also want to point out, `RectTransform` by default has a pivot point on its center, so the `(0,0)` will be in the center, not on the bottom-left.

The function you are looking for is [`RectTransformUtility. ScreenPointToLocalPointInRectangle`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/RectTransformUtility.ScreenPointToLocalPointInRectangle.html). To use it, you need the `RectTransform` of your UI object, if the `Render Mode` of your `Canvas` is set to `ScreenSpaceCamera`, you will need the camera and the screen space position, which is the mouse position. I mentioned that it was different depending on the `RenderMode` due to the camera parameter needing to be `null` if your `RenderMode` is `OverlaySpace` for the function to work.

Another note, you will most likely want to implement [`IHandlers`](https://docs.unity3d.com/2017.4/Documentation/ScriptReference/EventSystems.IPointerEnterHandler.html) to know when the cursor is inside of the specific UI element.

Here is some example code:

```
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.EventSystems;

public class TestScript : MonoBehaviour, IPointerClickHandler
{
    [SerializeField] private Canvas parentCanvas = null;        // the parent canvas of this UI - only needed to determine if we need the camera  
    [SerializeField] private RectTransform rect = null;         // the recttransform of the UI object


    // you can serialize this as well - do NOT assign it if the canvas render mode is overlay though
    private Camera UICamera = null;                             // the camera that is rendering this UI

    private void Start()
    {
        if (rect == null)
            rect = GetComponent<RectTransform>();

        if (parentCanvas == null)
            parentCanvas = GetComponentInParent<Canvas>();

        if (UICamera == null && parentCanvas.renderMode == RenderMode.ScreenSpaceCamera)
            UICamera = parentCanvas.worldCamera;
    }

    public void OnPointerClick(PointerEventData eventData)
    {
        // this UI element has been clicked by the mouse so determine the local position on your UI element
        RectTransformUtility.ScreenPointToLocalPointInRectangle(rect, eventData.position, UICamera, out Vector2 localPos);

        // we now have the local click position of our rect transform, but as you want the (0,0) to be bottom-left aligned, need to adjust it
        localPos.x += rect.rect.width / 2f;
        localPos.y += rect.rect.height / 2f;

        Debug.Log(localPos);
    }
}
```

Here is a gif of the code working in a test scene. The image I have has a width and height of 32. I zoomed in the window so the clicks could be as closer to the edge to show the coordinates are properly set.

[image: Example]

Comment: Can I get the localPos as an integer? I think if its a 32/32 pixel texture, It must not get an integer. Is done using mathf.clamp?

Comment: Use `Mathf.Round` on both the x and y components individually.

Comment: What if it's just a `Sprite` and not a UI element?